# Java Regex/Split

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm looking to split a string at the first `':'`, to prevent issues if the second part of the string contains a `':'`. I've been looking at Regexes, but am still having some issues, can somebody give me a hand?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you include an example of expected input and output?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [overload of split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) that takes a limit parameter:

```
String[] result = s.split(":", 2);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use 2 argument [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to specify the number of elements you want in your array obtained after split: -

```
String str = "rohit:jain:use:single:split";
String[] arr = str.split(":", 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice, that split uses regexps. And indexOf + substr can be much faster than split.